# PyMC3; create simple Linear Regression model with real-world datasets

Tags: regression, machine-learning, bayesian, python, pymc

#### The Linear Model

I understand the concepts of Bayesian Inference in that the observed data, $x$, is fixed, and the parameters, $\theta$, are the random variables that follow a particular distribution.  I thought the best way to understand this would be to code it myself using the `datasets` in `scikit-learn` (`Python 3.5.1`). I chose the regression dataset with the smallest number of attributes (i.e. `load_diabetes()`) whose shape is `(442, 10)`; that is, `442 samples` and `10 attributes`.

I want to create a simple **Linear Model**:  $$y = \alpha + \sum_{j=0}^{10} \beta_{j}*x_{j}$$ 
where $x$ is a vector w/ dims = `(10,)` and `y` is a predicted value (scalar for frequentist) and w/ Bayesian syntax
$$ y \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$$
$$ \mu = \alpha + \sum_{j=0}^{10} \beta_{j}*x_{j}$$
$$ \alpha \sim N(0,10) ;
 \beta_i \sim N(0,10) ;
 \sigma \sim |N(0,1)| $$
They chose a pretty broad prior to be safe

**Bayes formula:** "To compute this we multiply the prior $P(\theta)$
 (what we think about $\theta$ before we have seen any data) and the likelihood $P(x|\theta)$" http://twiecki.github.io/blog/2015/11/10/mcmc-sampling/

$$P(\theta|x) = \frac{P(x|\theta)*P(\theta)}{P(x)}$$  The above is the posterior and $P(x)$ is a normalizer that gets canceled out during **Markov Chain Monte Carlo** algorithm.

```
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
from scipy import stats
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes

np.random.seed(9)
%matplotlib inline

#Load the Data
diabetes_data = load_diabetes()
X, y_ = diabetes_data.data, diabetes_data.target

#Assign Labels
sample_labels = ["patient_%d" % i for i in range(X.shape[0])]
attribute_labels = ["att_%d" % j for j in range(X.shape[1])]

#Create Data Objects
DF_attributes = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=attribute_labels, index=sample_labels)
SR_targets = pd.Series(y_, index=sample_labels, name="Targets") 

#Describe Attributes
DF_describe = DF_attributes.describe()
#print(DF_describe)
#               att_0         att_1         att_2         att_3         att_4  \
# count  4.420000e+02  4.420000e+02  4.420000e+02  4.420000e+02  4.420000e+02   
# mean  -3.634285e-16  1.308343e-16 -8.045349e-16  1.281655e-16 -8.835316e-17   
# std    4.761905e-02  4.761905e-02  4.761905e-02  4.761905e-02  4.761905e-02   
# min   -1.072256e-01 -4.464164e-02 -9.027530e-02 -1.123996e-01 -1.267807e-01   
# 25%   -3.729927e-02 -4.464164e-02 -3.422907e-02 -3.665645e-02 -3.424784e-02   
# 50%    5.383060e-03 -4.464164e-02 -7.283766e-03 -5.670611e-03 -4.320866e-03   
# 75%    3.807591e-02  5.068012e-02  3.124802e-02  3.564384e-02  2.835801e-02   
# max    1.107267e-01  5.068012e-02  1.705552e-01  1.320442e-01  1.539137e-01
```

I checked out the details on `att_0`, the first attribute:

```
#Distribution of Parameters
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
sns.distplot(DF_attributes["att_0"],bins=50,ax=ax)
ax.vlines(DF_describe.loc["mean","att_0"],ymin=0,ymax=13,linestyles="--")
```

[image]

#### In this approach, how could one make a linear model with PyMC3 for this data?

I was following Thomas Wiecki's `PyMC3` tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqTUNJ1smYM at `35:38` in particular to get this framework:

```
model = pm.Model()

with model:

    # Define parameter priors
        #Mean
    parameter_mu_priors = [] #Coeficients 
    for j, attribute_label in enumerate(DF_describe.columns):
        prior = pm.Normal("prior_mu_%d" % j, 
                          mu = DF_describe.loc["mean",attribute_label],
                          sd = DF_describe.loc["std",attribute_label])
        parameter_mu_priors.append(prior)

        #Standard Deviation
    parameter_std_priors = []
    for j, attribute_label in enumerate(DF_describe.columns):
        prior = pm.Normal("prior_std_%d" % j, 
                          mu = DF_describe.loc["mean",attribute_label],
                          sd = DF_describe.loc["std",attribute_label])
        parameter_std_priors.append(prior)

#     # Define how data relates to unknown causes
    parameter_posteriors = [] #? Or are these likelihoods here? 
    for j, attribute_label in enumerate(DF_describe.columns):
        posterior = pm.Normal("prior_mu_%d" % j, 
                              mu = parameter_mu_priors[j],
                              sd = parameter_std_priors[j],
                              observed=DF_attributes[attribute_label])
        parameter_posteriors.append(posterior)

#     # Bayesian Inference via MCM
    start = pm.find_MAP() # Find a good starting point
    step = pm.Slice() # Instantiate MCMC sampling algorithm
    trace = pm.sample(1000, step, start=start, progressbar=True)
```

I get this error b/c I definitely did something wrong:

```
  TypeError: Ambiguous name: prior_mu_8 - please check the names of the inputs of your function for duplicates.
```

Comment: I think you are perhaps struggling with what you need to compute.  Have you looked at likelihood functions and MLE?

Comment: Hey that helped me out. Thanks again @probabilityislogic !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One mistake I was making was by treating each `beta` as it's own parameter but in reality, the `beta*x` was the parameter.  The `beta*x` was `mu` for the normal distribution that `y` follows and the `beta` vector itself was a random vector with particular distribution. Basically, I just followed the example here: https://peerj.com/articles/cs-55.pdf really good resource if somebody is struggling with the concepts btw.